# The process behind completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the process behind transforming $x^2+x+1$ into $(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34$?

Does that same method works for every time I want to transform an expression like $ax^2+bx+c$ into a square like $(a+b)^2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$x^2+x+1$$

and at first we concetrate our attention on $x^2$ and $x$ then

$$x^2+x=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$$

then we adjust for the constant term

$$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$$

This method always works for this kind of expressions.

Comment: I understood the rest, but why the $\frac14$ is negative after the square?
Thank you.

Comment: since  $\left(x+\frac12\right)^2=x^2+x+\frac14$ then to obtain $x^2+x$ we consider $ \left(x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Forget about the $1$ first, what would be $a$ and $b$ such that $$(ax+b)^2=x^2+x+\text{something}?$$

Answer: $a=1$ because of $x^2$, and therefore $b=\frac12$ because of $x$.

**Step 2.** What would be $c$ such that $$(x+\frac 12)^2+c=x^2+x+1?$$

Answer: $\frac34$ (pretty easy analysis at this point).

As for you last question, yes, this can be done with any quadratic polynomial.

Comment: You're welcome!